# Take MySQL Dump, Restore it in a Table With Superset of the Original Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to take a **MySQL dump** of `table1` with `columns A, C` and restore it in the `table2` that has columns `A,B and C`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: I meant something different. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Dump your table

```
mysqldump -h server -u user -p --no-create-info database table > output.sql
```

Modify in export the table name

```
sed 's/table1/table2/g' < output.sql > input.sql
```

Import in database

```
mysql -u user -p database < input.sql
```

Comment: This won't work. There is an extra column in the destination table. The solution I used was to restore the dump in a temp table, and add the additional column there, so that the temp table structure would match the table2's one. Then I took a dump of the temp table and restored it in table2. You can modify your answer and include the details, I'll accept your answer then.

Comment: Can you post your error? For work my solution need who new column can be NULL